# Integrating wrt to same parameter twice

Tags: calculus, integration

I was reading an answer to another [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156987/bayes-theorem-normalisation-denominator-and-likelihood) and I saw something like:

$$
\int \int f(\theta) d\theta d\theta = \int f(\theta) d\theta
$$

My calculus ia  a bit rusty but can someone tell me the intuitive reason why we can drop one of the integrals.

Comment: Err.. in general you can't. Perhaps it's not you who's the rusty one. ;)

Comment: Can you link the other question?

Comment: Isn't the first integral always $0$?

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the link.

Comment: The trick is that $\theta$ isn't $\theta$; it's using the same letter to refer to two different things, to confusing effect.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Sometimes people are careless, typically with substituting. e.g. if they've written the equation $1 = \int_0^1 1 \mathrm{d}x$, then later on they have some reason to replace $1$ with such an integral in a context where $x$  already has a meaning, they will blindly substitute $1 \mapsto \int_0^1 1 \mathrm{d}x$ which is confusing because the $x$ in the substituted version has nothing to do with the meaning that $x$ already had, so you have two completely different variables going by the name $x$. The right thing to do is to pick a new letter first: e.g. $1 \mapsto \int_0^1 1 \mathrm{d}y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see reasoning behind the answer. I quote it here:

> \begin{align*}
> \int \pi \left( \theta \mid y\right) d\theta&=\int\frac{f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right) }{\int f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right)d\theta}d\theta\\ &=\frac{\int f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right) d\theta}{\int f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right)d\theta}\\
> &=1,
> \end{align*}

The answerer simply uses that the denominator of the original integrand is nothing more than a number. It's hard to tell because they look like "indefinite integrals" but from the context it's clear that they are definite integrals, most likely over $\Bbb R$. Write, for example $$I := \int_{\Bbb R} f(y\mid\theta)\pi(\theta)\,d\theta$$
This is a real number! So, $$\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right) }{\int_{\Bbb R} f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right)d\theta}\,d\theta = \int_{\Bbb R}\frac{f\left( y\mid\theta \right) \pi \left(\theta \right) }{I}\,d\theta = \frac 1I\int_{\Bbb R} f(y\mid\theta)\pi(\theta)\,d\theta = 1$$

No integral sign is being dropped as you say, just factoring out of constants.

Comment: Ah ok. That makes sense. Thank you for the answer. I got confused when he said "where we can "take out" the integral in the denominator because θ had already been integrated out there."

Answer (score 1):

if the limits of integration were from 0 up to 1, then the equality would be true.

Comment: but this is not always true. Pick f identicaly 1 and calculate with the same limits of integration.

Comment: Do you mean that $\int_0^1g(x)dt = g(x)$?